# verify an rpm signature in C code?

Tags: c, rpm, signature

How can I verify the signature of the rpm package(which is signed using GPG) inside my C code ? 
Want to read the header of the rpm for the signature so that I can verify using openssl calls.

Am i even thinking in the right direction ?

Comment: If a dependency on the `rpm` executable itself is acceptable, you could perhaps exec `rpm --checksig ...` and check the exit code / output. It's perhaps not as elegant, but probably a lot easier.

Comment: Signatures are usually with GPG in any case.

Comment: Isn't the signature part of the rpm header ? Isn't possible to parse the rpm and get the signature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Programming RPM with C"](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-programming-c.html) from Fedora might help, specifically the section ["Reading the RPM lead and signature"](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch15s03s02.html). That's only the overview of some of the C calls; it then says "You can do more with the signature than merely reading past it, of course. Look in the online RPM documentation for more on verifying signatures."

Comment: I considered that route, but as I said "The easy way".

Comment: The documentation has nothing about that. The documentation is very, very poor, and contains, almost useless information, like `Fclose` instead of really working with the library.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to verify the signature is (in C code) to open a pipe to the `rpm` command to verify the package:

```
FILE *fp = popen("rpm -K mypackagefile.rpm 2>&1 ", "r");
...read the result with fgets, or whatever
pclose(fp);
```

From the command-line, a couple of examples of output:

```
$ rpm -K ncurses6-6.0-20150725.x86_64.rpm |for-paste
ncurses6-6.0-20150725.x86_64.rpm: (sha1) dsa sha1 md5 gpg OK

$ rpm -Kv ncurses6-6.0-20150725.x86_64.rpm
ncurses6-6.0-20150725.x86_64.rpm:
    Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID f7e48edb: OK
    Header SHA1 digest: OK (208298c8b2ee9db30f01c817b773ce30caf74034)
    MD5 digest: OK (88c6c126cc1dc4d2a38916c3fce448be)
    V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID f7e48edb: OK
```

In the first (non-verbose) case, the `gpg` is printed only if the signature verifies.  You use the `-v` verbose option to show details for the signature `f7e48edb`.

For reference:

- [Using rpm -K](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-checksig-using-rpm-k.html) (Maximum RPM)
- [Tools For Studying RPM Files](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-file-format-rpm-tools.html)  (Maximum RPM)
  These are probably *not* installed on your system.
- [tools/rpmsignature.c](http://adm.pepper.linuxfocus.org/doc/rpm-devel-4.0.4/apidocs/html/rpmsignature_8c-source.html)